# How to stop users from deleting Activities?

Tags: account, security, activities, org-wide-defaults

We have accounts OWD set to Private and OWD for Activities set as Controlled by Parent but people can still delete their activities on the Account for example if a call doesn't go well.

How can I prevent them from doing so?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A trigger that fires before delete can put an error on those records if they meet desired criteria.

```
trigger PreventDelete on Event (before delete) {
    if(UserInfo.getUserId() != "##justforexampleincaseyouwanttobeabletodelete###"){
        for (Event e : Trigger.old) {
            e.addError('Unable to delete record!');
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: +1 But I'd use a Custom Permission these days. After all, admins come and go, but permissions are forever.

Comment: @sfdcfox Permission Sets are a pain to check in Apex compared to Hierarchy Custom Settings.

Answer (score 6):

You can use an `Apex Trigger` which leverages the `SObject.addError` method. You should look into trigger best practices such as handlers, service/domain layer, etc, but the basic idea would look like:

```
trigger Event on Event (before delete)
{
    for (Event record : trigger.old)
    {
        record.addError('Customize this message');
    }
}
```

One note, it's good to build some sort of bypass to this functionality, as you may want to occasionally delete records as an admin or some such. You can use a `Hierarchy Custom Setting` to do so:

```
trigger Event on Event (before delete)
{
    if (ActivityTrigger__c.getInstance().preventDelete())
    {
        ActivityService.addError(trigger.old, 'Some error message');
        // you would have to actually implement an Activity Service layer
        // the addError method would just loop through the provided records
        // and add the error string to each
    }
}
```

Comment: Did you see the new FeatureManagement class? A Custom Permission is now even easier to use: `if(!FeatureManagement.checkPermission('CanDeleteTask')) {`...

Comment: Wha? That looks specific to package development? Well looks like I can scrap a utility class now. Sweet.

Comment: Found out about this this morning, tested in my sandbox, and it works outside of packages, too.

Answer (score 3):

If you want to do this declaratively, turn off the Delete permission for those users' profiles. Separate answer because totally separate approach.