# How can I Efficiently Check if the Running User has a Custom Permission?

Tags: apex, permissions, custom-permission, feature-management

Is there any way to check in `Apex` if the running user has a specific `Custom Permission`? The best I know of using available methods involves two separate SOQL queries:

```
public static Boolean doesRunningUserHavePermission(String apiName)
{
    Set<Id> accessiblePermissionIds = new Set<Id>();
    for (SetupEntityAccess access : [
        SELECT SetupEntityId FROM SetupEntityAccess
        WHERE SetupEntityType = 'CustomPermission' AND ParentId IN (
            SELECT PermissionSetId FROM PermissionSetAssignment
            WHERE AssigneeId = :UserInfo.getUserId()
        )
    ]) accessiblePermissionIds.add(access.SetupEntityId);

    return 0 < [
        SELECT count() FROM CustomPermission
        WHERE Id IN :accessiblePermissionIds
        AND DeveloperName = :apiName
    ];
}
```

And then I would need to run:

```
Boolean hasPermission doesRunningUserHavePermission('CanPerformSomeOperation');
```

Comment: related: https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/138561/soql-to-find-all-users-with-a-custom-permission/138563#138563

Comment: @CharlesKoppelman Check who answered it. :)

Comment: Oh I know, I just wanted to link them for knowledge management purposes

Answer (score 46, accepted):

As of the [Winter 18 Release](https://releasenotes.docs.salesforce.com/en-us/winter18/release-notes/rn_forcecom_isvforce_feature_management.htm), we can now use the [`FeatureManagement`](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_class_System_FeatureManagement.htm) class for this requirement. The above method can be removed entirely and I can simply call:

```
Boolean hasPermission = FeatureManagement.checkPermission('CanPerformSomeOperation');
```

Thanks to [@sfdcfox](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/users/2984/sfdcfox) for [pointing this one out](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/205622/how-to-stop-users-from-deleting-activities/205625#205625).

Answer (score 9):

Adrian Larson's answer of using `FeatureManagement`'s `static Boolean checkPermission(String customPermissionDeveloperName)` will **Efficiently Check if the Running User has a Custom Permission**.

Testing Apex when using `FeatureManagement`'s `static Boolean checkPermission(String customPermissionDeveloperName)` isn't so simple.  Often, using **Custom Permissions** will grant a User something private or special, and I want to make sure my Unit Test is doing what I think it's doing when a User both has and doesn't have the Custom Permission(s) in question.  So, I made a github repo, [TestCustomPermissions](https://github.com/flexchecks/TestCustomPermissions), to automate adding Custom Permissions.  See [README.md](https://guides.github.com/features/mastering-markdown/) for documentation and example.

Answer (score -2):

At `User` object, simply add formula

```
$Permission.<<Permission set name>>
```

and use this checkbox anywhere else in the Org.

Comment: Bloats the data model. New permission = new field?